# How do I fix an invalid JDownloader jar?

Tags: 11.04, installation, data-recovery, re-installation, jdownloader

I tried installing JDownloader using `apt-get`, but the installation was interrupted by power failure. Since then I've been trying to reinstall but it gives an "Invalid jar file jdupdate.jar" error.

Installation reports as successful but still gives the same error. I originally installed with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jdownloader
```

Comment: Just to be sure, did you type the " in the terminal? If yes, remove it from the command.

Comment: The exactly error is "Invalid or corrupt jarfile jdupdate.jar".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Jdownloader installer don't really install the software. The first time you run it it will download the jar to your home folder.

You should try to rename or remove the folder named .Jdownloader in your home folder. To see the folder use Ctrl+H. Then try to open the JDownloader again.

Hope it helps

Comment: removing the .jdownloader folder helped... Thank You.... I had trouble finding the the folder it's hidden...